# Which is a good fallback approach for non-semantic HTML5 browsers (IE6-8)?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, semantics

Say if Modernizr is not used (I am using it), which of these would be the best joint solution?

At the moment, I am using solution 1 with the first CSS option. No styles have been added to the `<aside>` tags as I'm not sure which of the HTML5 semantic tags can be stylized, and which cannot (in browsers that support them).

#### HTML 1) Semantic → Division

```
<aside role="complementary">
    <div id="right">
        ...
    </div>
</aside>

#right { ... }
```

OR

```
aside #right { ... }
```

#### HTML 2) Division → Semantic

```
<div id="right">
    <aside role="complementary">
        ...
    </aside>
</div>

#right aside { ... }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure the second option would be better.. But I say just continue using modernizr. If JS happens to be disabled then too bad for them. A low percentage of people are still using IE8<

Comment: You can also use an html shiv.

Comment: @JoshPowell I'm aware of that buddy, I'm simply asking which is the best HTML and CSS layout for the older IE versions. :)

Comment: Ahh I see I see, my apologizes. I would also agree with JoshC on your two options. The second one is contained inside of an known element for those previous IEs and will at least be contained the correct way.

Comment: @JoshPowell Awesome, thank you for the response. I was thinking about simply removing the divisions and relying on the new elements, but that would then _force_ users with IE8 or below to have JavaScript enabled. I'm not too concerned about IE6 or IE7 as my site will probably not even work properly with them anyway, but I understand that IE8 still has many users, and I'm not sure if requiring JS for a relatively popular browser is acceptable or not? Since choosing to ditch IE8 support would mean problems for XP users who don't use other browsers. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, and also, do you know which of the new semantic elements can be given CSS styles, and which cannot? I was under the impression that since they were all block elements, they could be given CSS, but I've been told that only certain elements can have styling. This is partially the reason for the `<div>` usage as well.

Comment: For the first part, here is a good article about javascript disabled users, http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html. I am a fairly new developer and I may know a lot about previous and past development practices but I never heard about an html element not being able to be styled. I could be wrong but I never had a problem with a `span` tag or any inline elements that were styled in IE8.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm referring to new HTML5 semantic elements like `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, `<main>` and `<footer>`. Apparently, some of those cannot have styles for reasons I cannot fathom.

Comment: Yes, older IE's won't apply styles (or anything else) to elements they don't know. And in fact, the HTML standard does indicate that a good error handling for unknown elements is to output the content, ignoring the start and end tags. So, IE simply follows the rules to the letter.

Comment: So I can apply IDs, classes and styles to the new tags using Modernizr, and with JS disabled, they will refuse to work?

Comment: @DylRicho that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to include modernizr as it has a built in HTML5 shim that enables you to apply styles to new semantic elements in browsers that were created before HTML5 like IE 7 & 8.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the answer. I have decided to not support IE7, and support IE8 but only with JS enabled. However, something I would like to know, is can I use the usual CSS styling that I can with `<div>` elements, with the new HTML5 semantic elements? And if so, are there any limitations? (e.g. any tags that cannot be given heavy styles?) Thank you!

Comment: Good choice on dropping IE 7 support. I understand the pain in having to support very outdated versions of IE. IE 8 came out 4.5 years ago and is a completely different browser than IE 11. I encourage you to help enterprises, etc upgrade so they can stop wasting money and driving us nuts! :)

Comment: Anyway, there is nothing you can style in the new semantic tags. I believe most if not all are block style tags, like a DIV. I might be wrong, but I have not had any issues styling any of the new elements. For the most part they are really just DIVs with a more semantic name. Now some of the attributes, like for INPUT wont work without a polyfil and you wont have pseudo classes, transitions and animation support sine they were not standards in March 2009.  My personal strategy, which is the same as the Guardian newspaper, is to server a core site for old IE, one without any JS, just CSS.

Comment: That's great. My version of IE just updated to 11 on my Win7 laptop, and I'm actually enjoying it (surprisingly!), but one thing is irritating me about it. When using the F12 dev tools to emulate the IE8 document mode, conditional comments fail to do their thing. I know that IE10+ no longer allow these comments for _themselves_, but I'm trying to see what my page will look like in IE8 and it just isn't possible. It worked fine in IE10, but Microsoft just had to tinker with it, didn't they?

Comment: I hope Microsoft fixes this since [it has been filed as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806767/conditional-comments-do-not-work-when-emulating-document-modes-via-f12-developer-tools). By the way, you have a great website with some very informative articles. You may have noticed my comments on some of them. :)

Comment: I would not look for that to be added back as it is part of the overall strategy to get enterprises to upgrade to the latest version of IE. That ultimately should fix the IE8 issues and we can all just focus on building awesome web applications! The goal is to make bad habits like browser sniffing go away.

Comment: I do suppose it has its advantages there too. Would you be willing to [check out](http://jsfiddle.net/hAST4/1/) my new layout for the desktop version of my website? Do you find any problems with the layout, including semantics and the coding structure itself? The mobile design will be a lot simpler. Thanks. :)

Comment: [Fixed the missing `<ul>` tags](http://jsfiddle.net/hAST4/2/). An easy slip-up in Notepad++!